# Textfield changes from rounded to cornered

Tags: ios, user-interface, storyboard, uitextfield

Trying to manipulate the design of an app, I am attempting to change the thickness of a textfield. I am setting the textfield thickness at runtime (I don't know the other way,) and if the value is greater than 0.2, it will square itself:

```
// cornered rectangle
self.tfHostname.layer.borderWidth=0.3;
self.tfHostname.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
// still cornered
```

If the value is less or equal to 0.2:

```
//rounded with no color changes applied to border
self.tfHostname.layer.borderWidth=0.2;
```

How do I increase thickness without changing the style?

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought the borderWidth was in pixels...?

```
[self.tfHostname.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
```

works fine for me.

Or try, instead of self.tfHostname.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

```
[self.tfHostname.layer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
```

Maybe you can replicate the style you're wanting to achieve this way

Comment: There most be something else going on, because that does not work for me. I must be missing some crucial code. Are you using Xcode 5.0.2 as well?

Comment: Please check the updated answer. And yes I'm using 5.0.2